# ImportError: No module named 'scikits'

Tags: python, anaconda

I have the scikits package in C:\Anaconda3\Lib.
I also checked the pythonpath using

```
import sys
sys.path
```

The path variable includes the path in which the package is available. Still i face the following error:

```
>>> import scikits
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'scikits'
```

I am using the following python/anaconda version:

> Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016,
>   15:01:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: does your module have an `__init__.py` file in the same directory as scikits.py? It won't find it if not (assuming it's in a different directory to your source file).

Comment: if not, could help to include a print out of your sys.path, and also the locations of the file you are importing, and where you are running your python command from.

Comment: Are you *sure* you have a package called `scikits`? The `scikit-learn` package can be imported using `import sklearn`

Comment: Yes i do have a scikits package. Its in the following path: C:\Anaconda2\Lib\scikits

Comment: and the output of the sys.path command is: ['', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.3.5-py3.5.egg', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\cryptography-1.0.2-py3.5-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-19.6.2-py3.5.egg']

Comment: Is the scikits you've downloaded for python3? it's in Anaconda2 which suggests a python2 package to me, but you say you're running python3.5.1.

Comment: when i run the python compiler, this is the information that i get:  Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 15:01:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: thats wat made me say that its Python 3.5.1

Comment: I was able to import it after i shutdown and restarted the command prompt. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4):

You can install scikits for yourself from the terminal by running:
`pip install --user scikits.audiolab`

Answer (score 3):

For those who still have the problem (the accepted answer is expired), try this

```
pip install scikits.bootstrap
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/scikits.bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
import sklearn 

from sklearn import linear_model
# and not
from scikits.learn import linear_model
```